# Transforming a sum of products in a product of sums

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, divisor-counting-function

I am studying the proof for the formula of $\sigma (n)$, the divisor function.
At a certain point there is this equivalence but I can't see how it works:

$$\sum_{b_i \in \{0,1,\dotsc a_i\}}{p_1^{b_1} \cdot p_2^{b_2} \dotsm p_k^{b_k}} = \prod_{i=1}^{k}{(1+p_i+p_i^{2}+ \dotsc+p_i^{a_i})}.$$

How is it possible to transform a sum like this in a product of sums?
Perhaps there is some combinatorics behind this but I don't see it.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try expanding out the product $(1+x+x^2)(1+y)(1+z+z^2+z^3)$ by hand to get some intuition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sum in the product, is the sum of divisors of $p_i$ the product of these sums contain every product without repetition, of their divisors not exceeding the original number.

Comment: why does the product of the sums not exceed the original number?

Comment: Neither say they don't go larger than the orignal number used as input. One simply does the termwise product of values of divisors first, then sums them. The second  sums the divisors of a given power in the original number, then multiplies all the individual sums together.